# convex sets in normed spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

[image]I know that the closed unit balls of center origion are convex sets in a normed space.
Can we say that open and closed balls are convex sets and speres are not cpnvex in normed spaces? (Here center may be any arbitrary point).
For example the below pictures is a ball in function space $C[a,b]$, so is it convex?

Comment: Is the circle convex in the plane? Or the sphere in the space?

Comment: @mfl, no they are not convex (being spheres in plane and space)...
my question is what about open and closed balls in a normed space?

Comment: The triangle inequality yields convexity of balls in normed spaces.

Comment: @LeBtz I have proved their convexity as you said by using triangle inequality but there is some problems of convexity of a ball geometrically....

Comment: We can define convex set geometrically as the set in which any line segment joining its two points lies with in it.... But I cannot see this in the case of the open ball of centre $x_{0}(t)=t^{2}$ and radius $r=1$ in the function space $C[a,b]$

Comment: Your picture is a perfect example. Yes, this is a convex set. You just need to realize that it is not convex in $\mathbb R^2$, that's something completely different. If you take two graphs out of this picture you can transform one into the other by staying inside the red area all the time.

Comment: @LeBtz thanks at least some body understand my confusion but honestly speaking I m still unable to get your point.... Now I m sure its not some thing like $R^{2}$